# manually clearing my ubuntu-based linux tmp folder while booted from a linux live cd

Tags: linux, filesystems

If it is a temporary folder, then nothing should be required to remain there.  Now I'm not looking to cause myself issues and I could just leave well enough alone but there are always folders and files in my /tmp folder.  Even after reboot.  And how do I know something isn't executing from in there or should I care?

If I boot from a live cd and mount my installed hard drive and delete everything in that temporary folder, on reboot back to my normal system, I shouldn't have any errors about missing this file or that program's view returning to default or how many other things I didn't think of that some other software is maintaining/using from the /tmp folder.

So my question is should I worry about this at all or can I continue with this procedure, confident no unwanted effects will arise?

Not that it should matter because I'm doing this while booted from a live cd but the normal installed operating system is Mint 13 with Mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the `/tmp` directory cannot be presumed to survive a reboot. And on more modern systems than the one you're using, the directory is in a tmpfs anyway, and thus its contents are always destroyed at shutdown. So, yes, it's safe to do what you're doing.